# Which is correct in this case? "the document" or "a document"

Tags: grammar, articles, zero-article

## a document

> "I was writing a document this morning which I need to submit to my
>   boss by the end of this week."

## the document

> "I was writing the document this morning which I need to submit to my
>   boss by the end of this week."

The situation behind this sentence is that I know which document I'm talking about but the person who would read this sentence doesn't know 
 which document specifically I'm mentioning.